# Possible to set parallelism of executed query in sql-editor of Ververica Platfrom?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using the Ververica Platform to play around with Flink-SQL. Therefore I am using the SQL  editor for developing my queries. When executing the query for previewing the result I see in Flink UI, that the job is executed with a parallelism of 1.

Is it possible to set the parallelism (in Ververica Platform) with which the preview job is executed?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can refer to https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/application_operations/deployments/scaling.html?highlight=parallelism

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      parallelism: p
```